# Need some advice to maintain a certain order within datasets within MySQL

Tags: mysql, dataset, many-to-many

Assume a list of names in a table called `authors`. Each author has written some books during his lifetime. Important: **You don't know the explicit dates when the books were published.** (If I would now the exact dates, I could just order by that in each query and I would be good.) You only know the order of the books' publication. The books are stored in a table `books`. We have a Many-To-Many-Relation between `authors` and `books`.

**The question**: How would you store the order of a publication history of each of the authors?

Example:

```
Luc - title_1
Luc - title_2
Luc - title_10
Luc - title_234

Peter - title_1
Peter - title_5
Peter - title_10
Peter - title_987

John - title_2
John - title_5
John - title_9

...
```

At the moment I am storing for each author a string of comma separated Values (primary keys of the books) to remember the order of the publications of a certain author in a column called `books_order`.

```
id    name      publication_order
...
4     john      (2, 5, 9)
...
```

But that is certainly the wrong way to go. How to normalize that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add an extra column called `sortorder` or somethin similar. The first book gets a `1`, the second a `2` ... etc. With that, you can use `ORDER BY author, sortorder` to get a list of books sorted by author and order of publication.

Comment: You mean in the relation table `author_book`? Would be (author_id, book_id, sortorder) then?

Comment: Yes, exactly that's whaat I meant.